# Function score ignored

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two nearly identical documents, one of which has the fields `CONSTRUCTION: 1` and `EDUCATION: 0.1`, the other with `CONSTRUCTION: 0.1` and `EDUCATION: 1`. I want to be able to sort results by the value of either the CONSTRUCTION or EDUCATION field

```
GET /objects/_search
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "match": {
                    "name": {
                      "query": "Monkeys"
                    }
                }
            },
            "field_value_factor": {
                "field" : "CONSTRUCTION",
                "missing": 1
            }
        }
    },
    "_source": ["name", "CONSTRUCTION", "EDUCATION"]
}
```

Returns the incorrect results:

```
{
  "took": 8,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 3,
    "successful": 3,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 1.7622693,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "objects__feed_id_key_pages__date_2019-12-10__timestamp_1575988952__batch_id_3gpnz7fc__",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "dit:greatDomesticUi:KeyPages:12",
        "_score": 1.7622693,
        "_source": {
          "CONSTRUCTION": 0.1,
          "name": "Space Monkeys - education",
          "EDUCATION": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "objects__feed_id_key_pages__date_2019-12-10__timestamp_1575988952__batch_id_3gpnz7fc__",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "dit:greatDomesticUi:KeyPages:11",
        "_score": 1.0226655,
        "_source": {
          "CONSTRUCTION": 1,
          "name": "Space Monkeys - construction",
          "EDUCATION": 0.1
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This only always returns the same results. Indeed if you misspell the field_value_factor field, you get the same score `"field_value_factor": { "field" : "WHATEVER",... }`. This suggests the field simply isn't being read.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic mapping was turned off. The EDUCATION and CONSTRUCTION fields were not mapped. Mystery solved!